# Почему класс виден в глобальном пространстве имен?

Tags: php

Файл include.php:

```
<?php
namespace get_content
{
require_once "c_get_content.php";
require_once "c_proxy.php";
require_once "c_string_work.php";
}
```

В каждом файле c_*.php находится по одному классу, больше ничего. (c_get_content, c_proxy, c_string_work)

Файл get_test.php

```
 <?php
 namespace get_test
 {
  class c_get_content
  {
    public static function FUUUUUUUUUUUUUU()
    {
        return "FUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU";
    }
  }
 }
```

файл test.php

```
<?php
require_once "include.php";
require "get_test.php";
//use get_content;
$get_content = new c_get_content();
```

Вопрос: почему класс  c_get_content виден в глобальном пространстве имен? Я его в файле include.php завернул в namespace get_content?
Скрипт работает, а по идее не должен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По всей видимости 'любимый' PHP применяет namespace только в приделах файла, если использовать include|require то на подключаемые файлы политика пространства имен не распространяется. Нужно зайти в каждый файл и создать в них свои субпространства имен.
Пример:

```
<?php
namespace get_content\c_proxy;
class c_proxy
{
...
}
?>
```

Для удобного обращения внутри самой библиотеки лучше использовать псевдонимы.
Пример:

```
<?php
use get_content\c_proxy\c_proxy as c_proxy;
require_once "c_proxy.php";
$obj = new c_proxy();
?>
```

Если не использовать псевдонимы а просто подключить пространство, то нужно набирать так:

```
<?php
use get_content\c_proxy;
require_once "c_proxy.php";
$obj = new c_proxy\c_proxy();
?>
```

Или без подключения:

```
<?php
require_once "c_proxy.php";
$obj = new get_content\c_proxy\c_proxy();
?>
```

Повторю, что все права на подключения и создание пространств имен действуют только внутри файла и работают только с классами и фукциями.